# How do I verify site ownership on Google Webmaster Tools through nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, google-webmaster-tools

Since a couple of years ago, Google Webmaster Tools site ownership verification process started to require that verification files have certain content, instead of simply being there and returning `200 OK`, and making sure that other nearby files would return `404 Not Found` etc.

With the new requirement, how do I serve the Google Webmaster Tools site verification file with `nginx.conf` alone?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you know that the verification file should be named `googled1085b59adc211cb.html` (and you are told after you add a site within Webmaster Tools), then you can place the following into the appropriate `server` context of your `nginx.conf`:

```
    location = /googled1085b59adc211cb.html {
            rewrite ^/(.*)  $1;
            return 200 "google-site-verification: $uri";
    }
```

---

P.S. A thought experiment would reveal that it is also possible to create a `location` through regular expressions that would now allow anyone to verify ownership of your site at any time and without having to get in contact with you, but I will omit such configurations at this time (to prevent unintended use), since anyone genuinely interested now has a very good starting point anyways. :-)

Comment: Why the rewrite as well as the return?

Comment: The rewrite cleverly removes the leading `/` from `$uri`. :-)  Otherwise, Webmaster Tools won't authenticate you, or you'll have to copy-paste the filename twice, making the snippet error-prone.