# Serve google domain verification file via nginx

Tags: nginx, google-webmaster-tools

To perform domain verification for google, I must serve a file at the root of my domain. The filename is typically `googleXXXXXXXXXXXXX.html` (those Xs are a hex substring).

So I copied it to my site's root (`/var/www/html/`), and edited nginx's config like this:

```
location ~* /google.+\.html$ {
  alias /var/www/html/$1;
}
```

Though I get a 404. I didn't hardcode the filename, but it fails even if I do.

---

Please note I know of this widely-used [trick](https://serverfault.com/a/477104/473183):

```
location = /googleXXXXX.html {
  rewrite ^/(.*) $1;
  return 200 "google-site-verification: $uri";
}
```

But I don't want to do that because it's not future proof - *I want to serve the file as is*.

Comment: Where have you placed the file? Is it in `/var/www/html`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, in the root. Which for me is `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: Are other files in the root being served correctly? Why do you need a special location for this one file?

Comment: @RichardSmith That's just how google wants it. BTW I figured it out and added my answer below. Since you're the resident nginx expert, do you know why it works but my original code didn't? I'm glad to get it working, but I don't understand why it works! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure why `alias` didn't work, but this works for me:

```
location ~* /google.+\.html$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
}
```